# selecting recurring dates in a date range that may or may not have a year

Tags: mysql, date-range, recurring-events

I have a table of users with various dates like birthday, date of hire, and annual review date. The birthday may or may not have a year, the date of hire does have a year, and the review date does not have a year.

I want to be return a query across a date range that returns the rows with the dates calculated for the year of the date range for these recurring events.

For example:
A user with the following:

```
dob:1980-05-05  
doh:2005-06-22  
review:0000-10-01
```

Then if I query for a range of say, 2012-05-01 to 2013-12-01 I'd like it to return records like:

```
Event,Date  
dob,2012-05-05  
doh,2012-06-22  
review,2012-10-01  
dob,2013-05-05  
doh,2013-06-22  
review:2013-10-01
```

I realize that this probably will be done in separate UNION queries on each date field which is fine. This isn't exactly the same problem as finding dates x days in the future as I need the recurring date with the proper year in the given date range which may be over multiple years if the range is large enough.

I can only think of doing this programatically. First checking if the start and end range span over a year. Then split the dates into start date to end of year, start of year to end date etc. and run a query for each span.

Comment: How are you going to represent the range in the query?  As a start date and end date?

Comment: Yes. The user would select and submit a start and end date in the app like 2012-05-01 to 2013-12-01.

I was thinking something like this:  

`SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(@startyear),'-',MONTH(dob),,'-',MONTH(dob)))  AS dob
FROM users 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(@startyear),'-',MONTH(dob),,'-',MONTH(dob))) BETWEEN @startyear AND @endyear`

But this depends on processing the start/end date as follows:

`2012-05-01 - 2012-12-31  
2013-01-01 - 2013-12-01`  
  
And doing a UNION of the query with the two ranges for example